# JBoss AS 7 Datasource to SQL Server using Windows Integrated authentication

Tags: java, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, datasource, jboss7.x

The title is pretty explanatory. I need to configure a datasource in JBoss AS 7 that will connect to a SQL Server 2008 R2 database using windows integrated.

I have searched a lot but all the examples just use SQL authentication.

Comment: Have you ever done integrated auth in jboss4/5 with sql?

Comment: No I didnt, should it be the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to download this driver http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=11774

Then read the instructions and you will see that you will need to add a dll so the java runtime is capable of use the native layer.

You will also need to run the service as the user that has permission to the database.

I'd recommend start with jboss 5.1 and try the auth in that platform to make sure it works, i.e. create a simple war file that reads from the database and configure the datasource to use integrated auth.

If that works then you are half way to your objective.

Configuring integrated auth in jboss 7 may be a little bit more challenging because of https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/MODULES/Native+Libraries

And if you find issues I also recommend asking in the jboss.org jboss-as message board. They are usually very helpful.